# Notification does not show time in ICS 4.0 (API 14)

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am using the following code to show a notification

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Hello World!");
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
```

According to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html)/[tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

```
You can set an explicit value with setWhen();
if you don't it defaults to the time that the system received the notification.
```

Problem is I am not getting the `defalut time` in the notification.

[image]

**--------------------WORK AROUND---------------------**

Get the current time using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and then pass it to `when()`

```
long curr_time = System.currentTimeMillis();

mBuilder.setWhen(curr_time);
```

Let me know if this could be solved without a work around. :)

Comment: but you do not use setWhen(); now...

Comment: it is not required as per the docs, if you want to show default time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in early versions of ICS; the timestamps should appear again as of version 4.0.3 ([fixed here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/e37233038ed8775ebdb8ade95a7ff2c150c840c7)).

Comment: So have to use the work around to support all the devices in the market :)

Comment: There shouldn't be that many 4.0.0 devices out there in the wild; a quick look at the [dashboard](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) shows that nearly all ICS devices are on 4.0.3+.

Comment: Yes but this doesn't work on any ICS version. I am using 4.0.4 :)